# Proper handling of 128..255 chars in C

Tags: c, string, character-encoding, pointer-conversion

I need to process some Win-1251-encoded text (8-bit encoding, uses some of 128..255 for Cyrillic). As far as I can tell, C was created with 7-bit ASCII in mind, no explicit support for single-byte chars above 127. So I have several questions:

- Which is the more proper type for this text: `char[]` or `unsigned char[]`?
- If I use `unsigned char[]` with built-in functions (`strlen`, `strcmp`), the compiler warns about implicit casts to `char*`. Can such a cast break something? Should I re-implement some of the functions to support `unsigned char` strings explicitly?

Comment: For your purpose, you may check your compiler, if it use signed or unsigned values for char. Check all compilers you may use. Most compilers have also a flag to change the "signess" of char.

Answer (score -1):

C has three distinct character types, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, and `char`, which may be either signed or unsigned. For strings, you should just use `char`, since that will play nice with all the built-in functions. They'll all also work fine on characters with numeric values greater than 127. You should have no problems with your case using `char`.

Comment: `char *` is okay for `strlen`, but others, like `isspace`, take `unsigned char` values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: no. isspace take `int`. In general single characters are passed as `int`, for compatibility with old C.

Comment: Yeah. Usually you can use standard string functions regardless the signess of char (POSIX systems, and many other, where *char is a single byte*). But this is valid only if you are using functions which do not check the semantic of the characters (e.g. for sorting, checking alphanumeric characters, etc.)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: As I wrote, `isspace`, and the other `<ctype.h>` functions, takes an `unsigned char` **value**. The **type** of the argument is of course `int`, but the value in it should be non-negative or `EOF`, per C 2018 7.4 1: “In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.” If you have an array `x` of `char`, and `char` is signed, passing `x[i]` to `isspace` can pass a negative value, and the behavior is not defined.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: There are also problems in the other direction. For example, `fgetc` returns an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`. If this value is assigned to a `char`, it is converted. If `char` is signed and the `unsigned char` value is not representable in `char`, the behavior is not portable—the C standard says the result of the conversion is implemented-defined or raises an implementation-defined signal.